# Uniform Convergence of Derivative and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am aware that the following proposition is similar to *Theorem.3.7.1. in Analysis II by Terence Tao* and *Theorem.7.17 in Baby Rudin*.

Given a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \geq 0}, f \in C^1 [-1, 1]$ and $f_n \longrightarrow f$ uniformly.

Define $F_n(t) := \displaystyle \int_{-t}^{t} f_n(s) ds$ and $F(t) := \displaystyle \int_{-t}^{t} f(s) ds$.

How do we prove that $F_n \longrightarrow F$ uniformly and $F'_n \longrightarrow F'$ uniformly please?

The professor gave the following sketch of the proof:

By FTC I,
$(F_n - F)(x) := \displaystyle \int_{x_0}^{x} (f_n - f)(t) dt$

And by fundamental estimate, $|(F_n - F)(x)| \leq \text{Length}(I) \cdot \displaystyle \sup_{I} |f_n - f|$, where $I$ is an interval.

However I am unsure how to **bound $|F'(x)|$ or $|(F'_n - F')(x)|$** (in order to show the uniform convergence of $F'_n$)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Write out explicitly what F' is

Comment: Ahhh, I think by FTC I, $F'_n(x_0) = f_n(x_0)$ and $F'(x_0) = f(x_0)$, since $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then $\lim \sup |f_n - f| = 0$, hence we have the uniform convergence of $F'_n \to F'$?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$F(t) := \displaystyle \int_{-t}^{t} f(s) ds =\int_{-1}^{t} f(s) ds - \int_{-1}^{-t} f(s) ds $$

Hence $$F'(t) = f(t) - f(-t)$$ and so we get
$$|(F'_n - F')(x)| = |f_n(x) - f_n(-x) - f(x) + f(-x)| \le 2\sup_{[-1,1]}|f_n - f|$$

Comment: Lovely answer! Thank you :)